# Custom POST/PUT route/endpoint based on meta value

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I'm currently making a store which is receiving it's data from external sources. Being new to the world of editing/creating REST API, I've come across a problem. The problem is that the external source have no idea what ID the product gets in woocommerce so update/delete products is not possible with the current endpoints/routes. However, the external source does have it's own ID on it's product and I've stored this in a custom meta field in woo and I can see it and update it through api on Postman.

How can i create a new endpoint/route that uses the custom meta field called externalProductId and use this to update the product instead of  the woocommerce ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, which I particularly did in my case ... Create a field id_product_woo in your external bank, the time you create the product in Woocommerce, it returns a JSON with the information of the product created, including the ID inside Woocommerce... When you create or update a product in Woocommerce, you then pass the id stored in the id_product_woo field of your external bank.
Apparently, this for me, worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for replying Paulo! This is actually what we ended up doing! The problem was that I didn't have access to the external bank, but after reaching out to the developers at the other end, we managed to fix it with the method you are describing.